# Display WinForm (C#) from DLL in vbscript

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, vbscript

I've created a simple Form in a DLL to be displayed/called via VBScript.

```
namespace Playground_DLL
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
    }

    public void ShowForm()
    {
        this.Show();
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    public void Hello()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello");
        Application.Run(this);

    }
}
```

I'm trying to receive the DialogResult of this Form after clicking the Button.
But I'm struggling to make the Form visible.
The DLL is registered and the form can be created from within vbscript.
But after calling the form.ShowDialog() method, the script stops (or is waiting for the dialogue to close), but the form isnt Shown.

Only if I call the (experimental) Hello() function, the form is visible. (but only if I'm showing a messagebox before calling application.run).

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Here's my vbscript snippet.

(The whole script and form don't really do something. It's just to learn / understand new concepts)

```
Dim test
Set test = CreateObject("Playground_DLL.Form1")
test.topMost = True
test.Hello()
Msgbox(test.DialogResult)


Dim test
Set test = CreateObject("Playground_DLL.Form1")
test.topMost = True
Dim result
result = test.ShowDialog()
Msgbox(result)
```

Comment: Do a simple google search on how to call a C# Dll from VB Script.. have you at least thought to do that..?

Comment: The problem isn't calling the DLL.  That's working.. It's the form that isn't showing up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create GUI in C# and call in VBScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943253/create-gui-in-c-sharp-and-call-in-vbscript)

Answer (score -1):

You initialize the window, but never show it.  Your sequencing and syntax are off...

```
public void ShowForm()
{
    this.Show();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Hello();     //Display your MessageBox based on the button click
    this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
}

public void Hello()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hello");
}

Dim test
Set test = CreateObject("Playground_DLL.Form1")     //This is where you initialize
test.topMost = true
//test.Hello()                                      //This is to display the message box - not Form1
test.ShowForm();                                    //This displays Form1
```

Comment: Well calling test.ShowDialog()  should bring up the form visible, right? But nothing happens.  Ignore Hello() and ShowForm() those were just for testing purpose.  ShowDialog   / Show are the 'built in' Form functions to show my form after initializing. But the don't make it visible.

Comment: try `test.Visibile = true;`

Comment: resulting in an error, saying the form is already visible while Calling ShowDialog()